# Nginx location regex doesn't work with proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, regex, proxypass

I'm trying to get these 2 location directives working in Nginx but I'm getting some errors back when booting Nginx.

```
   location ~ ^/smx/(test|production) {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:8181/cxf;
    }

    location ~ ^/es/(test|production) {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9200/;
    }
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block
```

Does it sounds familiar to anyone? What I'm I missing here?

Answer (score 71):

A small addition to the great answer from [Xaviar](https://serverfault.com/a/649196/677):

If you happen to be not so well acquainted with nginx, there's an important difference between adding the slash to the end of the `proxy_pass` directive.

The following **does not** work:

```
location ~* ^/dir/ {
  rewrite ^/dir/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://backend/;
```

but this one does:

```
location ~* ^/dir/ {
  rewrite ^/dir/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://backend;
```

The difference being the `/` at the end of the `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: That trailing `/` fixed my configuration problem, it was hard to catch, thanks!

Comment: rewrite does not work for POST unfortunatelly

Comment: section 3 of https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/ helped in my case

Answer (score 33):

It tells you that **the URI** in the proxy pass directive can't be used in a regex location. This is because nginx can't replace the part of the URI matching the regex in the `location` block with the one passed in the `proxy_pass` directive a generic way.

Simply imagine your location regex is `/foo/(.*)/bar`, and you specify `proxy_pass http://server/test`, nginx would have to map your location regex to another one on an upper level because you don't want to end with `/foo/test/bar/something` but with `/test/something`. So that's not possible natively.

So for this part using the following should work :

```
server {

   [ ... ]

    location ~ ^/smx/(test|production) {
        rewrite ^/smx/(?:test|production)/(.*)$ /cxf/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
    }

    location ~ ^/es/(test|production) {
        rewrite ^/es/(?:test|production)/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
    }

}
```

However, it won't be possible to rewrite redirects to match the location block URI pattern because it rewrites the current URI being processed, making it impossible to change the `Location` header based on the *initial request* before rewrite.

Comment: moving the path into a rewrite rule worked for me.  thanks.