# Nginx's location and proxy_pass missing a request when hash is present in url

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have this config

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  root        /usr/share/nginx/htdocs;
  index       index.html index.htm;
  port_in_redirect off;

  location /somepath/ {
      proxy_pass http://someinternalserver/somepath/;
  }

  location /health {
    return 200;
  }
}
```

When I access it like this, http://our-external-fqdn/somepath/ it works.

However, when I access it like this, http://our-external-fqdn/somepath/# I get redirected to our local development setup which is http://localhost:8000

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've specified an exact URL not a regular expression. Try this

```
location ~* /somepath/ {
  proxy_pass http://someinternalserver/somepath/;
}
```

If that doesn't work please curl (with show headers, option is -D I think) the URL to see what's going on, or use Firefox with "Live HTTP Headers". Post the output for that request along with your access logs.

Comment: I got an error after I restarted nginx - nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:138

Comment: Edit your original question to include your your nginx.conf and and site configuration files. Add this to the bottom of your original post, don't replace your original question. I think though my answer is incorrect, and that you may need to go back to the original configuration. I use fastcgi_pass with regular expression matches, but not proxy_pass. Suggest you do my "if that doesn't work" and post that information as well.

Comment: Also, read this, which says remove the trailing slash from the end of your proxy_pass statement http://serverfault.com/questions/649151/nginx-location-regex-doesnt-work-with-proxy-pass

Comment: Tim, that's all my nginx.conf file. It's really that simple.

Comment: i removed the trailing slash but I still got the same error

Comment: Revert the changes and do my "if that doesn't work". Post the result in your first post under the existing text.