# Nginx rewriting url for proxy passing

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

So I have two nginx server in a kubernetes cluster. I want that one nginx server acts as a reverse proxy for the other that serves my phpmyadmin files.

For accessing my phpmydadmin from the first server, the user has to type:
`https://mynginx.example/phpmyadmin`
From that I want my nginx server to rewrite the URI before he proxy pass with replacing /phpmyadmin by /.

I write this for now

```
      location                /phpmyadmin {
            rewrite           /phpmyadmin(/.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass        https://phpmyadmin.default.svc.cluster.local:5000;
      }
```

But actually when it returns me 404 error and when I saw logs on nginx that serves phpmyadmin I see:

```
19 open() "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

It doesn't seem to replace my /phpmyadmin by /.

All my config file is:

```
server {
        listen                  80 default_server;
        listen                  [::]:80 default_server;

        return                  301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
      listen                  443 ssl default_server;
      root                    /www;
      index                   index.html;

      ssl_certificate         /tls/tls.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key     /tls/tls.key;

      location                /phpmyadmin {
            rewrite           /phpmyadmin(/.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass        https://phpmyadmin.default.svc.cluster.local:5000;
      }

      location                ~ /wordpress(.*) {
            return            307 $scheme://$host:5050$1;
      }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx location regex doesn't work with proxy pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/649151/nginx-location-regex-doesnt-work-with-proxy-pass)

Comment: it exists a similar question already but i believe if you look at the location of phpmyadmin you may have forgotten something, to see what you've forgotten take a look at your WordPress location ;)

Comment: The error message does not correspond to either of the two `server` blocks you posted. Please include the complete nginx configuration by running `nginx -T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it ! It was an issue with my regex (/.*), I remove the / and now it works
Thanks for your helps and suggestion I follow the links and learned some things x)